# How System Can Know financial year?

Tags: php

I am new in php. I have a scenario in which i saved a document number depend on financial year. In my scenario i want that when financial year is changed number start from zero.
Here is code how i get financial year

```
   if (date('m') > 6) {
    $year = date('Y') +1;
}
else {
    $year = $date('Y');
}
```

My current financial year is 2016, but when July start my financial year will be 2017.

here i am confuse that how system can know that financial year is changed and start numbering from zero.

Comment: I do not understand the question.. the code is not working? the financial year is just theoretical financial thing - nothing to do with system right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` to add 1 year in current year.

```
if (date('m') > 6) {
    $year = date('Y',  strtotime("+1 Year"));
}
else {
    $year = date('Y');
}
echo $year;
```

Comment: use above code will help you and solve your problem. @sunny

Comment: Dear my problem is that how system can knows that financial year is changed and start numbering from zero

Comment: you need to use crone for that on server. Crone will check every day and if july month start it will increment your financialId and use it throughout the project. @sunny

Comment: Can you give a demo please

Comment: You need to search about it. This will set by cpanel of your project. Just google it about `crone job`.